# Unable to identify error in ./screens/WriteComplaint

Tags: react-native, expo

im writing this code for an app template just a quick project and came across this problem. I have imported the database also just look into it please, it would be a big help.

photo= [code error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzKES.png)

also find the link for my project https://snack.expo.dev/@ayushmanchaudhuri/946cee

the error is in writecomplaint

Comment: Please don't post errors as code and link to external code repositories. Make your question self-contained and post a minimal, reproducible example that shows the error here ...

Comment: Maybe it's work on mobile tabs or device, and not work on web app. Please check on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `WriteComplaint.js`,a lot of undefined `styles` are there. `styles.title`, `styles.author`, `styles.storyText`, `styles.submitButton` and `styles.buttonText` is not defined in StyleSheet.

Comment: Thanks. I actually put them now thinking ill define them later. I found out that the actual problem was in config fixed it now thanks.